# wsimport issue in ANT task

Tags: java, eclipse, wsimport

This appears when the ANT is running. 
Does anyone know what I can set the path right? I am using Eclipse and it's using JDK, also JAVA_HOME is set correctly.

```
[wsimport] command line: wsimport "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" ...
```

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
I believe the actual reason is that in build.xml, ${java.home} is pointing to JRE rather than JDK... while i have set JAVA_HOME in Windows, also point to the JDK in eclipse.

Comment: Can you include the whole error message or stack trace?  Some context would be really helpful here...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, used this code

See if this help:
https://gist.github.com/rponte/850815

---